# Send fcm notification on change in rest api or on POST

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a REST API written in Laravel. I'm using flutter as frontend and I'm using firebase to send notifications.

I'm trying to send firebase push notifications to my users when a POST request is called on the API. How can I do this with or without a cloud function?

Comment: Please include a sample of your code that you've tried as well as any errors you encountered.  That way it will be easier for others to help you.

Comment: As @DHerls suggests, can you please include a sample of your code along with the errors? It'll be easer for us to help you.

Comment: check out this post. This might help https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-fcm-rest-api-7719925f2e3e